# Duvidas Mysql ENGINE=FEDERATED

Tags: mysql

Boa noite,

Alguém consegui me ajudar, estou em um projeto onde preciso fazer relacionamentos de tabelas em outros servidores, estou utilizando da seguinte forma:

Aqui estou criando a url de conexão dinamicamente:

```
set v_link = concat('mysql://',v_mysql_user,":",v_mysql_senha,'@',v_mysql_server,'/',v_mysql_banco,'/',v_mysql_tabela);

CREATE TABLE tbl_server1 (
 id int(10) NOT NULL,
 campo1 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 campo2 varchar(1),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=FEDERATED 
 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 CONNECTION= v_link;
```

Mas ao tentar criar a tabela, da erro na variavel v_link que criei, alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Consegui resolver com ajuda desse link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273701/variables-in-create-statement